# Search for index of Character in list (python)

Tags: python, arrays, list

```
myList = ['AAAbbbbbbbbbbbbbbAbbbbbb', 'AbAbbbAbbbbAAAbbbbbbbAbb', 'AbAbbbbbbbbAbAAAAbbbbbbb', 'AAAbbbbbbbbAbAAbAbbbbbbA', 'bbbbbAbbbbbAAAAbAbbbbbbb', 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbAAAbbbbbbb']
```

I want find every "bbbb" in this list. I also want to get the position, where the "bbbb" begins f.e.:
`myList[0][3]`(0 for the index and 3 for the index/position in the string).
I also want to be able to search for something like `myList[1][5]`.
How can I get these 2 "axis" (x = position in string & y = index of list)???
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
res=[]
for i in range(len(myList)):
    for k in range(len(myList[i])-3):
        if myList[i][k:k+4]=='bbbb':
            res.append((i,k))

>>> print(res)
[(0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (0, 9), (0, 10), (0, 11), (0, 12), (0, 13), (0, 18), (0, 19), (0, 20), (1, 7), (1, 14), (1, 15), (1, 16), (1, 17), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 17), (2, 18), (2, 19), (2, 20), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 17), (3, 18), (3, 19), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 17), (4, 18), (4, 19), (4, 20), (5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (5, 10), (5, 17), (5, 18), (5, 19), (5, 20)]
```

Comment: What 's the result when you type `print(myList)`  ?

Comment: I´m sorry. Now i tried it in Sublime instead of python ide and it works

Comment: Your function doesn't seem correct. Your return 2 times (array and res) which is not correct

Comment: Now i tried it with another arrayand it doesnt work:

`res = []
array = ['XXX00000000000000X000000', 'X0X000X0000XXX0000000X00', 'X0X00000000X0XXXX0000000', 
         'XXX00000000X0XX0X000000X', '00000X00000XXXX0X0000000', '00000000000000XXX0000000']

for i in range(len(array)):
 for k in range(len(array[i])-3):
  if array[i][k:k+4]=="XXX":
   res.append((i,k))
print(res)
print(array)`

Comment: It must be: if array[i][k:k+4]=="XXXX":

Comment: No i wanted to search for "XXX" not for "XXXX" so i changed it to ...[k:k+3] = "XXX":
ANd now it works
Thank you a lot

Comment: What can i do that it doesnt count it twice if there is XXXX?
Now it counts it twice starting at the first and the second X

Comment: This is a different problem. Please add a new question for this, so that we will dicuss it there and avoid long dicussions in comments. Cheers

Comment: Ok did it!
Thanks a lot for all your help

Comment: Sorry but can you please say me how here because my other question that i postet got closed so nobody can answer xD.
I just wanna know what I can do that it only counts in the list if it´s "XXX","XXXXXX" or "XXXXXXXXX".

Comment: Try this:

`res2=[i for i in res if i[1]==0 or myList[i[0]][i[1]-1]!='b']`

This will keep all items of res only if previous character is not 'b'